# Magento2: How to install MSI for M.2.4.2

Tags: magento2

I'have removed all modules MSI for 2.4.2 via this module

```
https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory
```

composer unistall yireo/magento2-replace-inventory

Currently I need rewrite all modules MSI 2.4.2. Any solution how can I to do?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to do. do you want to install magento's default msi?

Comment: yes, Because  via above extension I removed all modules from MSI  and I now need rewrite this.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the closed issues on the meta package repo, you will see this: [How do i get packages back?](https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-tools/issues/3). Maybe the dialog there will help you understand what's going on.

From what I understand, the tool will alter your composer.json and use the replace mechanism to remove the modules you don't want. The user who opened the issue mentioned above also said that in the end he found a way to put the modules back by adding them to the *app/code* folder.

Obviously this is not the most orthodox way and I am asking myself whether you could:

1. install a clean version of the Magento 2.4.2 in another folder
2. do a diff between its composer.json and your current installation's composer.json
3. see which lines were altered and manually update your current installation's composer.json with those from the clean install
4. then run a `composer install` to bring back the modules the tool removed.

***Disclaimer:*** I have no idea if this will work properly, it's just an idea for you to explore. **I would say this is worth a try on a test machine.**

Good luck and I can't wait to see if you sorted this out!

Comment: in which composer.json folder should I check?

Comment: the one in the root of your project, at the same level with folders 'app' and 'vendor'.

Comment: I have a little problem. Because I searched composer.json files but can't see anything related to MSI. So far I did this: I downloaded pure magento 2.4.2 and added the missing modules MSI that were removed to vendor / magento but it doesn't work. ehh can you please some hint. ?

Comment: well this is not what i suggested :) the purpose was to work only with the composer.json files from your current project and the one with a clean magento install.

Comment: ok, i wanted to go easy. ;]  So I will try to install pure magento with your solution